# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out error on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, java, apache-commons-httpclient, connection-timeout

While trying to execute an http get, I keep getting the connection time out error. The same code runs perfectly fine when I run it on my system, but this problem occurs when I try to run it on my server. The same url when tried with curl returns response consistently. Both the systems have ubuntu 10.04, and are using open-jdk. Both use commons-httpclient-3.1.jar, and no multi-threading, multiple connections are involved. While I understand there has to be something different somewhere which is causing the difference in behaviour, I am not able to figure out where to start looking. Any pointers?

Comment: where do you want to onnect to, please provide code

Answer (score 0):

Is your server sitting behind a proxy?  We've had to make all our apps making remote calls (outside our datacenter) proxy aware, otherwise the calls will be blocked by the proxy server.  Another thing to try is take java out of the picture and make some basic calls with curl.

Comment: The calls made with curl work fine consistently, while the java client works once in a number of attempts. Forgot to mention that in the question. The server is not behind a proxy. Besides, curl works fine so I guess that's not the issue.